# How to setup openHAB to work with a RaZberry ZWave binding?

Tags: hardware, home-automation, zwave, razberry, openhab

I have a [RaZberry](http://razberry.z-wave.me) [z-wave](/questions/tagged/z-wave) module on my Raspbery GPIO pins and it works well. I use [raspian](/questions/tagged/raspian) and [java 8](http://www.savagehomeautomation.com/projects/raspberry-pi-installing-oracle-java-se-8-with-javafx-develop.html).

Now I want to use [openHAB](http://code.google.com/p/openhab/) version 1.3 with the new Z-Wave binding.

The [documentation] (http://code.google.com/p/openhab/wiki/ZWaveBinding) on binding tells that the zwave:port has to be /dev/ttyS0 on linux systems:

```
# Z-Wave controller port
# Valid values are e.g. COM1 for Windows and /dev/ttyS0 or /dev/ttyUSB0 for Linux
zwave:port=/dev/ttyS0
```

I set up my x.items and x.sitemap and x.rules file but the z-wave does not work.

```
14:25:01.430 INFO  o.o.b.z.i.p.ZWaveController[:128] - Starting Z-Wave controller
14:25:01.443 INFO  o.o.b.z.i.p.ZWaveController[:627] - Connecting to serial port   /dev/ttyS0
14:25:02.319 ERROR o.o.b.z.i.p.ZWaveController[:642] - null
14:45:47.212 INFO  o.o.c.s.AbstractActiveService[:201] - ZWave Refresh Service has been shut down
```

I also tried to set it to
    zwave:port=/dev/AMA0

but that causes the same:

```
15:12:21.996 INFO  o.o.b.z.i.p.ZWaveController[:128] - Starting Z-Wave controller
15:12:22.011 INFO  o.o.b.z.i.p.ZWaveController[:627] - Connecting to serial port   /dev/AMA0
15:12:22.643 ERROR o.o.b.z.i.p.ZWaveController[:642] - null
15:12:31.464 INFO  o.o.c.s.AbstractActiveService[:201] - ZWave Refresh Service has been shut down
```

What is the right value?

Comment: can someone with 150 P or above please add the tags: zwave razberry openhab

Comment: Done, max of 5 tags so I removed gpio since the OP has demonstrated that the GPIO interface is working I felt the specific product tags were more relevant.

Comment: make sure to shut down Z-Way before using another program. Also check permissions on /dev/ttyAMA0 and make sure user ``pi`` do have them

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure that the permissions are ok. But'll double check them again at weekend when I have time.

Comment: Prrmissions are ok. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right device is

> /dev/ttyAMA0

Make sure that the openHAB process has sufficient rights and that Z-Way (if installed) is stopped (/etc/init.d/Z-Way stop).

Because of the uncommon name of the Device, you have to tell openHAB at startup that this is a RXTX device - append

```
  -Dgnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts=/dev/ttyAMA0
```

to start.sh (or start_debug.sh)

That should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Openhab 1.7.1 from apt-get, and I was getting the error:

```
[ERROR] [b.z.i.protocol.ZWaveController] - Serial Error: Port /dev/ttyAMA0 does not exist
```

I had to add

```
 -Dgnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts=/dev/ttyAMA0 \
```

to `/user/share/openhab/bin/openhab.sh`  (JAVA_ARGS_DEFAULT= section)

not to `/etc/init.d/openhab`

(this is in addition to adding the openhab user to the dialout group in `/etc/groups`)